# Add/Subtract amounts from column in one list to "cell" in another list

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, workflow, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to build two lists to keep track of our purchase orders we have. My 
 two lists looks like this:

List 1: PO

> ```
> +-----------+-----------+-------------+
> | PO        | Amount    | Used/Left   |
> +-----------+-----------+-------------+
> | 654654654 |     50000 |          ?? |
> | 123123123 |     30000 |          ?? |
> | 789789789 |      5000 |          ?? |
> +-----------+-----------+-------------+
> ```

List 2: Purchases

> ```
> +-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
> | Supplier  | PO        | Description   | Amount    | Received  |
> +-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
> | Some name | 654654654 |     Blah blah | 1654      |    Yes/No |
> | Some name | 123123123 |     Blah blah | 2441,41   |    Yes/No |
> | Some name | 789789789 |     Blah blah | 154       |    Yes/No |
> | Some name | 123123123 |     Blah blah | 4521,52   |    Yes/No |
> | Some name | 789789789 |     Blah blah | 160       |    Yes/No |
> +-----------+-----------+---------------+-----------+-----------+
> ```

So here we go. 
In List 1 we have our PO's and the max usable amount and a column to the used amount.
In List 2 we have the purchases made on the different PO's.

What I would like to accomplish is getting the sum of the "Amount" column connected to the different PO's from list 2 to be added in the "Used/Left" column in List 1 under the right PO. So List 1 is always showing the remaining amount on the different PO's

Even better if the sum of the amounts will be subtracted from the full amount in the "Amount" column in List 1

I am guessing using Calculated fields or workflows? I would prefer no workflows as i never made one ;)

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**First,** In your case, the Calculated Column is not considered a solution! the calculated column formula is only scoped to the current row fields in the same list.

**Secondly,** the workflow is not a flexible solution especially if you will run the workflow on list that already have content. Meanwhile, you can try the mentioned solution at [Getting the sum of a column from one list copied/updated to a field in another list](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/87c04e66-64ef-45bd-87e0-9be9392cad00/sharepoint-2010-getting-the-sum-of-a-column-from-one-list-copiedupdated-to-a-field-in-another-list?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious)

**In my opinion,** the flexible solution for your situation is creating **Event Receiver** on `Item Added` & `Item Updated` on list 1 to perofrm your calculation in a flexible manner!

Comment: I don't know anything about Event Receivers, can you point me in the right direction to make that happen?

Comment: check this bro,  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5b1f04/creating-simple-event-receiver-in-sharepoint-2013/